# Subclassing - uiviewcontrollers: where could I find some examples?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, subclassing

I'm a little bit confused about the custom UiViewController inheritance.

For example if I have:

```
    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
       IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

           id <MyDelegate> aDelegate;
           AnObject *myObject;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyDelegate> aDelegate;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) AnObject *myObject;

    @end
```

---

A subclass of MyViewController "inherits" the protocol declaration? that is, can or not it override the methods in them, setting the delegate and datasource properly without redeclaring  in its interface?

And what about property and their possible deallocation?

I would some examples, links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a protocol is simply a promise that a class implements required and (optionally) optional methods. That's all it is. You can override these in subclasses and such however you want.

The data source and delegate of the *table view* are set to `self`, and `self` implements the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

In your sub-class, `self` is the sub-class. Overriding the protocol methods in the sub-class will work perfectly fine. The table view is the one defined in the parent class.

In short, the answer is **yes**. If you want more information I suggest you read up on how `@protocol` works.